# How to plot vector of bootstrapped slopes in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I've been using ggplot2 to plot the results of bootstrapping various statistical outputs such as correlation coefficients. Most recently, I bootstrapped the slope of a linear regression model. Here's how that looks using the `plot()` function from the `graphics` package:

```
plot(main="Relationship Between Eruption Length at Wait Time at \n 
 Old Faithful With Bootstrapped Regression Lines", 
 xlab = "Eruption Length (minutes)", 
 ylab = "Wait Time (minutes)", 
 waiting ~ eruptions, 
 data = faithful, 
 col = spot_color, 
 pch = 19)

index <- 1:nrow(faithful)
for (i in 1:10000) {
    index_boot <- sample(index, replace = TRUE) #getting a boostrap sample (of indices) 
    faithful_boot <- faithful[index_boot, ]
    # Fitting the linear model to the bootstrapped data:
    fit.boot <- lm(waiting ~ eruptions, data = faithful_boot)
    abline(fit.boot, lwd = 0.1, col = rgb(0, 0.1, 0.25, alpha = 0.05)) # Add line to plot
}
fit <- lm(waiting ~ eruptions, data=faithful)
abline(fit, lwd = 2.5, col = "blue")
```

That works, but it depends on a workflow where we first create a plot, then add the lines in a loop. I'd rather create a list of slopes with a function and then plot all of them in ggplot2.

For example, the function might look something like this:

```
set.seed(777) # included so the following output is reproducible
n_resample <- 10000 # set the number of times to resample the data

# First argument is the data; second is the number of resampled datasets
bootstrap <- function(df, n_resample) {
    slope_resample <- matrix(NA, nrow = n_resample) # initialize vector 
    index <- 1:nrow(df) # create an index for supplied table

    for (i in 1:n_resample) {
        index_boot <- sample(index, replace = TRUE) # sample row numbers, with replacement
        df_boot <- df[index_boot, ] # create a bootstrap sample from original data
        a <- lm(waiting ~ eruptions, data=df_boot) # compute linear model
        slope_resample[i] <- slope <- a$coefficients[2] # take the slope
    }
    return(slope_resample) # Return a vector of differences of proportion
}

bootstrapped_slopes <- bootstrap(faithful, 10000)
```

But how to get `geom_line()` or `geom_smooth()` to take the data from `bootstrapped_slopes`? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT: More direct adaptation from the OP

For plotting, I presume you want both the slopes and the intercepts, so here's a modified `bootstrap` function:

```
bootstrap <- function(df, n_resample) {
  # Note 2 dimensions here, for slope and intercept
  slope_resample <- matrix(NA, 2, nrow = n_resample) # initialize vector 
  index <- 1:nrow(df) # create an index for supplied table
  
  for (i in 1:n_resample) {
    index_boot <- sample(index, replace = TRUE) # sample row numbers, with replacement
    df_boot <- df[index_boot, ] # create a bootstrap sample from original data
    a <- lm(waiting ~ eruptions, data=df_boot) # compute linear model
    slope_resample[i, 1] <- slope <- a$coefficients[1] # take the slope
    slope_resample[i, 2] <- intercept <- a$coefficients[2] # take the intercept
  }
  # Return a data frame with all the slopes and intercepts 
  return(as.data.frame(slope_resample))      
}
```

Then run it and plot the lines from that data frame:

```
bootstrapped_slopes <- bootstrap(faithful, 10000)

library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_abline(data = bootstrapped_slopes %>% 
                sample_n(1000), # 10k lines look about the same as 1k, just darker and slower
              aes(slope =  V2, intercept = V1), #, group = id), 
              alpha = 0.01) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, color = "red")
```

---

#### Alternative solution

This could also be done using `modelr` and `broom` to simplify some of the bootstrapping. Based on the main help example for `modelr::bootstrap`, we can do the following:

```
library(purrr); library(modelr); library(broom); library(dplyr)
set.seed(777) 

# Creates bootstrap object with 10k extracts from faithful
boot <- modelr::bootstrap(faithful, 10000)
# Applies the linear regression to each
models <- map(boot$strap, ~ lm(waiting ~ eruptions, data = .))
# Extracts the model results into a tidy format
tidied <- map_df(models, broom::tidy, .id = "id")
# We just need the slope and intercept here
tidied_wide <- tidied %>% select(id, term, estimate) %>% spread(term, estimate) 

ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_abline(data = tidied_wide %>%
     sample_n(1000), # 10k lines look about the same as 1k, just darker and slower
     aes(slope =  eruptions, intercept = `(Intercept)`, group = id), alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, color = "red") # spot_color wasn't provided in OP
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jon! I hadn't seen examples with a whole pipe inside the call to geom_abline(). That opens up a lot of territory. Looking forward to building on these examples.